# How to copy data from user profile page (profile.php) to theme customizer

Tags: plugins, php, theme-development, profiles, theme-customizer

i am trying to figure out how to copy data from user profile page (profile.php) to theme customizer.
i want to copy some data from some fields, when theme is activated. and stored the data in theme customizer, so when the user will enter to theme customizer he will see all data there.
i using gravity forms as register form with some custom fields.
the same fields i have created in the user profile page (profile.php). so when user register, this data stored in user profile page. like **address, phone and etc...**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

anybody that looking for solution here is what i found that work for me.
to get some data from any field in profile page you need to use this function:

```
<?php get_the_author_meta( $field, $userID ); ?>
```

then if you want to update some value in theme customizer you can use this function:

```
set_theme_mod( 'field name', '$value' );
```